# What is the correct form of possessive case for the noun 'mice'?

Tags: possessives

**Mice** is plural form of **mouse**. It is an animate noun. I wonder what possessive does it have in the plural? Should we write:
1)

> mice's behavior

2)

> mice' behavior

or how?

Comment: **Behavior of mice** is a simple solution.

Comment: geese's, mice's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's confusing, but we just use **'s**.

> #### [Irregular Plurals](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-possessive.htm)
>
> Some nouns have irregular plural forms without s (man → men). To show possession, we usually add 's to the plural form of these nouns:
>
> ```
> singular noun         plural noun
>   my child's dog        my children's dog
>   the man's work        the men's work
>   the mouse's cage      the mice's cage
>   a person's clothes    people's clothes
> ```
>
> (English Club)

The issue of whether to use **'s** or just **'** only occurs when the word ends in an *s* (e.g., the collars of many dogs, the dogs' collars).

I don't think there is often a problem when the possessive is an irregular plural like above.